# Use capture group in re.sub

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, python-3.x, python-2.x

I have the following code:

```
>>> s = 'https://www.microsoft.com/ja-jp/store/tv/%E7%BE%8E%E7%94%B7-%E3%82%A4%E3%82%B1%E3%83%A1%E3%83%B3-%E3%82%B9%E3%82%BF%E3%83%BC%E8%AA%95%E7%94%9F-%E3%83%8E%E3%83%BC%E3%82%AB%E3%83%83%E3%83%88%E7%89%88-subtitled/season-1/8d6kgwzj5pvv'
>>> re.sub(r'\/((tv)|(movies))\/\S+\/', '/**tv|movies**/x/', s)
'https://www.microsoft.com/ja-jp/store/**tv|movies**/x/8d6kgwzj5pvv'
```

I am trying to pull the "tv" or "movies" value for the `xxx`. How would I do that, to get:

```
>>> s = 'https://www.microsoft.com/ja-jp/store/tv/x/season-1/8d6kgwzj5pvv
```

Comment: `re.sub(r'\/((tv)|(movies))\/\S+\/', r'/\1/', s)`

Comment: @Alik please see updated question. This would chop off 'season-1'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
re.sub(r'\/((tv)|(movies))\/\S+\/', '/\\1/', s)
```

Edit: To match the second case, you can use:

```
re.sub(r'/((tv)|(movies))/[^/]+', r'/\1/x', s)
```

Comment: thanks, could you please see the updated question, I left out a part of it, so the regex was cutting off the 'season-1' part.